# Class that does things to another class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class that is essentially a wrapper for a large data object on a database. Looks like this:

```
public class ServerWrapper {
    private DataObject object;

    public ServerWrapper(DataObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void doAThing1() {
        getSomeStuff();
        // do stuff that modifies this object
    }

    public void doAThing2() {
       getSomeStuff();
       // do other stuff that modifies this object
    }

    private List<> getSomeStuff();
}
```

This is the problem: there are many, many "doAThing" methods. And some of them are quite large. Also, a lot of them use other private methods also in ServerWrapper. Ideally, I'd like to break off these public methods into their own classes, like ThingDoer1, ThingDoer2, but I don't know the best way to do this.

Something like this:

```
public class ThingDoer1{
    public void doAThing1(ServerWrapper wrapper) {
        wrapper.getSomeStuff();
        // do the thing to wrapper
    }
```

seems very smelly; it's tightly coupled to ServerWrapper (ServerWrapper calls it and it calls ServerWrapper), plus it needs to either do stuff with the object it's given (which is bad), or make a copy, do the stuff, then return the copy.

Really, I think what I'm looking for is a set of partial classes, just to make this monster of a class more manageable; but I'm using Java, which doesn't support that.

Is there some standard practice for breaking down a large class like this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The point of the wrapper is to add server-side functionality to a database object. For example, this object needs to be "expired". What this requires is getting all the associations to the database table, then doing several validations on the object and those associations, then setting a bunch of fields in the object and its associations, then calling a database update on the object and all those associations. Having all that code inside the ServerWrapper makes sense to me, but there are several fairly complex operations like that the need to happen, so the class itself is getting rather large.

Comment: You're asking too generally. What is the purpose of this wrapper? Is it more like a decorator? An adapter? Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @chrylis Thank you, please see my edit.

Comment: That sort of thing sounds like an awfully complicated class that doesn't have architectural business as a decorator. I would generally say that if you're manually expiring objects, then write the expiration process as a separate service and then fire it on some sort of schedule.

Comment: @Evan so this getSomeStuff() is used by number of doThing() methods??

Answer (score 2):

But it doesn't need to be tightly coupled with `ServerWrapper`:

```
public class ThingDoer1() {
    public void doAThing1(List<> theList) {
        // do the thing to object
    }
```

Then in `ServerWrapper`:

```
public void doAThing1() {
    new ThingDoer1().doAThing1(getSomeStuff());
}
```

I'd go further maybe:

```
public class ThingDoer1() {
    private final List<> theList;
    public ThingDoer1(List<> theList) {
        this.theList = theList;
    }
    public void doAThing() {
        // do the thing to object
    }
}
```

In `ServerWrapper`:

```
public void doAThing1() {
    new ThingDoer1(getSomeStuff()).doAThing();
}
```

Which is more of a [Replace Method with Method Object refactor](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html).

Comment: I have done something similar in my spring application... I made an interface named IComponentBA and made a list of these objects in my controller so that whenever needed, they could be irritated and executed....